# Как остановить выполнение цикла без использования потоков?

Tags: delphi

Допустим у меня на форме расположены две кнопки: Button1 - запуск цикла программы. Button2 - кнопка для останова программы.

Код кнопки Button1:

```
begin
  CheckBox1.Checked:=False; // Запретить CheckBox1 -  в начале.

  ...

  while not Eof(f1) do begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Readln(f1,s);
    // если в CheckBox1 отмечен значит цикл останавливается
    if CheckBox1.Checked=True then
      exit;
```

Код Button2:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckBox1.Checked:=True; // Разрешить чекбокс и тем самым остановить программу
end;
```

Как при нажатии, на вторую кнопку - остановить цикл программы?

Важное условие - мне нужно простое решение **без использования потоков**. Данный код не будет предназначен для работы в промышленных приложениях, так что подойдут и не самые "правильные" решения.

Comment: @Kromster, с потоками еще разбираюсь. Я пробую, пока что, простые примеры. Для того, что бы научиться, сначала, без потоков. А потом, уже, перейти к более сложным - примерам. Вопрос задала потому что: хочу изучить его полностью.

Comment: @Kromster, Хорошо, тогда сейчас удалю вопрос. Меня просто интересовал вопрос - если без потоков то я правильное решение сделала  или ?

Comment: @Kromster, давайте, только мне нужно отредактировать или ? просто я не знаю, можно ли это, мне, делать?

Comment: из чего у вас тут ответ то предполагается? "да правильно", или что?

Comment: @teran, Предполагается что: Если неправильно то напишите как правильно сделать ?

Comment: ну дак работает ведь код-то? с чего у вас возник вообще вопрос, правильно тут что-то или нет? Или вам надо разъяснить просто, что делает `ProcessMessages` и почему с ним работет, а без - подвисает?

Comment: @teran, Он то работает, но интересно - возможно есть более простой вариант ? Или, при данном условии, это самый оптимальный вариант ?

Comment: можно убрать чекбос и заменить его на `private` поле формы. Разве что чек вам нужен для визуализации. В остальном проще уже не будет.

Comment: а в коде `if CheckBox1.Checked=True then` стоит заменить на простое `if CheckBox1.Checked then` ибо это бессмысленно

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, то покажите, озвученный вариант - на примере ? И я, как раз, отмечу это как ответ. Не могу понять что значит фраза:  "заменить его на private".

Comment: Зачем вообще Button2 отмечающая чекбокс, почему бы не убрать Button2 и просто не отмечать чекбокс для останова программы?

Comment: @Kromster, Можно и так, но как то некрасиво получается - без кнопки :). Хорошо сделаю так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, имеем форму с двумя кнопками `StartButton` & `StopButton`. Первая цикл запускает и выполняет, вторая останавливает.

Для контроля того следует ли остановить цикл в класс формы добавим булевую переменную-член класса (заменив ей ваш чекбокс, который не ясно зачем нужен).

Класс формы выглядит следующим образом:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StartButton: TButton;
    StopButton: TButton;

    procedure StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FStopped: boolean;              // - флаг останова
  public

  end;
```

Начнем с конца, кнопка стоп просто устанавливает флаг в значение `true`

```
procedure TForm1.StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FStopped := true;
end;
```

Кнопка Старт же наоборот сначал сбрасывает значение в `false`, затем запускает бесконечный цикл. В цикле проверяя значение `FStopped`.

```
procedure TForm1.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FStopped := false;

  while true do begin
    Application.ProcessMessages();

    if FStopped then break;

    //doSomething()
  end;
end;
```

Что вообще тут происходит. При запуске приложения создается основной поток. В целом работа приложения представляет собой бесконечный цикл приема и обработки оконных сообщений, на этом основан весь принцип работы windows.  В dpr-файле  вы можете найти строку `Application.Run`, которая в этот цикл обработки и входит.

Когда в основном потоке вы начинаете писать какой-то ресурсоемкий код (например, бесконечный цикл), то ваше приложение перестанет обрабатывать эту очередь сообщений, не будет реагировать на движения мыши, не будет кликов по кнопкам, все остановится пока эта сложная задача не будет выполнена.

В связи с этим все ресурсоемкие задачи обычно выносятся в отдельные фоновые потоки, которые потом синхронизируются с главным, если это требуется.

Если же мы в наш бесконечный цикл добавим вызов `Application.ProcessMessages()`, это позволит приложению далее обрабатывать очередь входящих сообщений и соответственно реагировать.

*зы: если кто-то хочет дополнить ответ, о преимуществах и недостатках данного подхода, и вынесения кода в рабочий поток, то можете сделать ответ общим. ценного тут ничего нет.*

Comment: @Kromster вы думаете, что ваши 2 пробела в отступах чем-то правильнее чем мои 4? Или с какой целью вы их исправили?

Comment: скорее по привычке причесал код к стандарту самой Delphi (таб по умолчанию равен 2 пробелам). и подчистил авто-добавленные комментарии. Если не согласны - пожалуйста откатывайте )